# Can't correctly count the frequency of word form in NLTK, Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, nltk, frequency, lemmatization

I'm a beginner in Python and I've got a question. I want to count lemmas (not only words, but lemmas!) of a text and to line them from more frequent to less  frequent. I use this code:

```
with open('D:\YandexDisk\Mishas_project\Книги\E\E.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as inp:
    txt = inp.read()

points = ['.', ',', ';', ':', '!', '?', '"', '--', '‘', '---', '–', '—', '«', '»', '-', '…', '(', ')', '*', '_', '¬', '“', '”', '\\', '`', 'ù', '/', 'ï', 'ß', ',']
out = "".join(c for c in txt if c not in points).lower().replace('\n', ' ').replace('&', 'and')

import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def get_wordnet_pos(word):
    tag = nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1][0].upper()
    tag_dict = {"J": wordnet.ADJ,
        "N": wordnet.NOUN,
        "V": wordnet.VERB,
        "R": wordnet.ADV}
    return tag_dict.get(tag, wordnet.NOUN)

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
st = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, get_wordnet_pos(w)) for w in nltk.word_tokenize(out)]

dic= {}
for key in st:
    if key in dic:
        value = dic[key]
        dic[key]=value+1
    else:
        dic[key]=1
```

At this step I find out the mass of mistakes in the work that NLTK has done. For example, the code can't differentiate 'land' as a noun and as a verb form, it doesn't understand 'break' and 'broke' as word forms of the lemma 'break' (it's pretty strange while it understands 'break', 'breaking' and 'broken' as word form of the same lemma).

So, to resolve this problem I try such a code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize
str_text = "He was a boy. I am a boy. I break a vase. I broke a vase. I'm breaking a vase. I land succesfully. The land was here"
tokened_text = nltk.word_tokenize(str_text)
tagged_text = nltk.pos_tag(tokened_text)
```

It gives this result:

```
>>> tagged_text
>>> [('He', 'PRP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('a', 'DT'), ('boy', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), ('boy', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('break', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), ('vase', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('broke', 'VBD'), ('a', 'DT'), ('vase', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('I', 'PRP'), ("'m", 'VBP'), ('breaking', 'VBG'), ('a', 'DT'), ('vase', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('land', 'VBP'), ('succesfully', 'RB'), ('.', '.'), ('The', 'DT'), ('land', 'NN'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('here', 'RB')]
```

The code perceives 'land' as a noun and 'land' as a verb, it sees different forms of 'break' as a verb forms - so, I think I can use it to improve my main code, but as I understand  this approach can't lemmatize word forms.

So, to make my research I have to link two approach: one of a WordNet and another one of Tokenize. But I think it must be a more simple way to do it 'cause NLTK is a flexible and quite sofisticated toolkit.

Could somebody help me?